# The Search page is empty. Is it too empty?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, design, search

In the Stack Overflow search [site](https://stackoverflow.com/search) (markdown: `https://stackoverflow.com/search`), and the Meta Stack Overflow search sites are empty.

[image]

There are only:

- Top navigation bar
- "Search" label
- Textbox + Search button + Advanced tips expandable thingy
- "Ask Question" button

Here are my thoughts:

- The search page is ~66% white (and ~82% when omitting the footer), the main question list ~72% white (omitting the footer). Although the value looks close, the search page UI looks much emptier.
- This page looks scary to me (seriously) since it's so empty and guide-less.

So, I'd say:

**Should we put something down there?**

For example, when you type a question, a drop-down box shows similar results. Or alternatively, we can move "Advanced Search Tips" down there.

I'm no UI expert, but just some little thoughts. Please also share your opinion on this page.

---

**Note:**

Moderator Cody Gray♦ reminded me that Google (`Google.com`) also has an empty search page. I think Google's search bar is centered in the page, but there is a huge gap between searcher bar and footer in SO search page.

Comment: You know who else has a mostly-empty search page? [Google](http://google.com). Just throwing that out there.

Comment: Oh darn, I must have forgotten Google :(

Comment: Not sure there is link to that search page from anywhere on the site..Users use the top search bar in home..Also the least visited search page would probably be [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search)

Comment: @suraj stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask comes with the search page link. And you're correct, meta should be the least visited search page.

Comment: @SagarV https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6piW.png (obviously that link is not doing its job...)

Comment: I didn't remember when I last visited that ask page. Sorry for that comment

Comment: It took me while to remember when did I last used StackOverflow search. I prefer the old [empty page search](https://www.google.com) always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving question page is definitely on our radar. Not only that empty state view (which could get some touch of love), but also regular results view.

However, it is lower priority for our team at the moment. So for now I'm gonna tag it as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).